# Open file from file browser in already running application

Tags: java, swing, file, ubuntu, singleton

I have written an application in Java/Swing, which edits a bespoke filetype.

I have also implemented drag & drop to add further files to edit. I have added mimetypes to my desktop environment so that a double click starts my application & opens the file.

My Problem is, when I double click on a second file, it starts a second instance of my program. How do i setup this to open the second file in the initial instance of my application ?

As this is StackOverflow, not AskUbuntu...What needs to be done on the **Java/Swing** side to enable this to work?

Comment: Which application, and how are you opening it?  Are you using ProcessBuilder?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Its my own application. The problem is to have my application listen & process file open requests from the desktop. Not using ProcessBuilder.

Comment: Since it's your own application, there's no way we can help you debug the problem without seeing code.  If you would create a [mre] of your application, it would be helpful.

Comment: There is no code to post, as I don't know where to begin implementing this feature. Many java applications have this feature, so it is possible, a starting point is what is needed.

Comment: [How to allow running only one instance of a Java program at a time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920386/how-to-allow-running-only-one-instance-of-a-java-program-at-a-time)

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177189/how-to-implement-a-single-instance-java-application.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc - Thanks All - I will investigate further with the linked questions.