# Single Instances or Single program open

Tags: java

I created a program using java.
now that Im done I build it.
How can I make my program can run just once or 
what they called Single Instances.

Comment: See [how-to-implement-a-single-instance-java-application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177189/how-to-implement-a-single-instance-java-application)

Answer (score -1):

This is how you create a Singleton Class

```
public class MyClass
{
  private MyClass instance;

  private MyClass() { }

  public static MyClass getInstance()
  {
     return instance == null ? new MyClass() : instance;
  }
}
```

So where-ever you are trying to invoke the class do it this way

```
public class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
     MyClass mc = MyClass.getInstance();

     //With this only one instance of your class is possible
  }
}
```

Comment: The OP is asking how to have a single instance of the program (i.e. one JVM), not how to create a singleton class.