# block the socket port to run only a single instance of jar file in windows

Tags: java, sockets, jar, executable-jar

I am working on Java Swing application . I have created the jar of my application , when user 
clicks on the jar application starts. If user clicks multiple times on the jar then multiple instances of the jar run.

SO how can i stop multiple instances of running of Java jar file?

Comment: And what does this have to do with sockets exactly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement a single instance Java application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177189/how-to-implement-a-single-instance-java-application)

Comment: And what does 'block the socket port' have to do with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose a location where to create a lock directory. On startup, try and create it: if it fails, you know another instance is already running.

When the program shuts down, delete the directory.

Note: a directory and not a file, since directory creation is atomic and Java doesn't have `O_CREAT|O_EXCL`, except for Java 7+.

Comment: how can i create the lock directory