# How to check in java if an application is aleady running before launching new instance?

Tags: java, instance

I want to make my application single instance application. While launching a new instance i want to check for already running instance. My application is written in java.

Comment: Why not use a `Singleton` bean?

Comment: or here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177189/how-to-implement-a-single-instance-java-application

Answer (score 0):

Your application can listen to messages on a port. You can send a ping and if it is timed out, then it is not running and if it responds, it is running.