# How to stop a program run to times to times when click on it (java)

Tags: java

Java bin/jar when I double clicked on it first time it opens but again double-clicked on it. it appears the same window like the first one and it open it multiple times how can I stop it. I just want a solution that how can I open a jar like a professional software.
Sorry for my bad english

Comment: http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/ ?

Comment: Use a mutex. Here's one idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177189/how-to-implement-a-single-instance-java-application

Answer (score 0):

- First check that Java is installed on your machine, by typing "java -version"
- If java is installed then you need to goto under that folder where the jar file is present.
- Type command "java -jar "
- In the above command type your file name in place of