# Ensure a single instance is running

Tags: java, lockfile

I have some code to ensure a single instance of my app is running, using a lock file:

```
public static boolean ensureSingleInstance(String appName) {
    try {
        String path = Paths.get(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"),  appName + ".lock").toString();
        File file = new File(path);
        RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
        if (randomAccessFile.getChannel().tryLock() != null) {
            file.deleteOnExit();
            return true;
        }
    } catch (IOException ignore) {
    }
    return false;
}
```

This works 99.9% of the time.  And then yesterday, in production, a second instance of the app successfully started...

How can this code fail?

Comment: Different value of the system property, different value of the app name...?

Comment: The obvious ones that you probably checked are a) different values for the ``getProperty`` call or b) a different ``appName`` (case sensitive etc)

Comment: @AndyTurner the fact that this isnt an exact copy+paste of the actual code makes answering this question even harder

Comment: Does the file exist on the same device the processes are running?

Comment: What happens when `ensureSingleInstance` returns false?

Comment: @StephaneM the app exits if it returns false.

Comment: @f1sh the only thing I did was bowdlerize the appName; all instances use the same hard-coded appName, and I'm having a hard job imagining that `System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")` changes under me :(

Comment: The code itself looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2002948/507738). So we can assume that that solution actually works. The only thing I can imagine is indeed that the value of either `appName` or `System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")` actually changed.

Comment: @MCEmperor I think I got it https://community.oracle.com/thread/2044019 - its about the same.  Hmm, yeah I can't spot any race anywhere else :(