# How to check if java project is running

Tags: java

I have java project (with eclipse IDE) and i want to check if this project is running in the process.
Is there a way to run the project just one time ?

Comment: There are in theory several ways to ensure that only one instance of your program is running. The question is if you should do that (aka if it is really necessary). In many cases it's far simpler to just... run the application once.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177189/how-to-implement-a-single-instance-java-application, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177189/how-to-implement-a-single-instance-java-application/2002948#2002948.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly, once you have a main class with something in it to run, then simply run it in the IDE

[image]

Once you've done this there should be a console that comes up at the bottom (or wherever you may have it placed).

[image]

Comment: Why down vote this?? I think this is the appropriate response to the question *"want to check if this project is running in the process."*