# How to check The System tray is already exists or not?

Tags: java, swing, system-tray

Is there any way that I can check if a system tray already exists? When I keep running the program to create a system tray then multiple occurrences appear, which means multiple programs are running. So, I need to check the system tray is already there?

Comment: You really want to check if only one instance of your application is running. Refer to this SO question. [How to implement a single instance Java application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177189/how-to-implement-a-single-instance-java-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
boolean trayExists = SystemTray.getSystemTray().getTrayIcons().length > 0;
```

Comment: @BulbulAhmed [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).